# Insertar multilenguaje en Enum con codigos de error

Tags: c#, net, traducción

Tengo una aplicaciones con mis codigos de error en un Enum, algo asi

```
public enum ResultCode
    {
        [Description("Operation succeeded")]
        OK,

        [Description("There was a generic internal error")]
        ERR_GENERIC,
    }
```

Y la implementacion

`return Result.Failed(ResultCode.ERR_GENERIC, ResultCode.ERR_GENERIC.GetDescription());`

Esto funciona de manera correcta

Ahora estoy tratando de agregar multilenguaje a los codigos de error
Para eso estoy usando la interface IStringLocalizer
Por el momento hice la prueba y me funciona bien implementandolo de la siguiente manera

```
var prueba = _sharedResourceLocalizer.GetString("prueba").Value ?? "";
var prueba2 = _sharedResourceLocalizer["prueba"];
```

El problema que estoy teniendo es que no se como agregar esto al Description
Ya que como es un enum no puedo hacer lo mismo que utilice en el controller para realizar la prueba
Tampoco puedo crear una clase static ya que no puedo usar el constructor para pasar por parametro la interfaz **IStringLocalizer**

Tienen alguna idea de como podria realizarlo?

Muchas gracias

Saludos